# Atiyah-Macdonald Exercise 1.6 generalization

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I solved the following exercise from Introduction to Commutative Algebra (A&M):

A commutative ring $A$ is such that every ideal not contained in the nilradical contains a nonzero idempotent. Prove that the nilradical and Jacobson radical of $A$ are equal.

I was able to prove it. I am wondering is there any general characterization of such a commutative ring? Thank you so much.